# Python Polars attach attributes to Series in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to add attributes (variable labels) to the series of a Polars DataFrame that describe the data, in the hope that these would remain there at least in operations such as selecting or renaming some columns. It turns out that this does not work the way I hoped it would. Is there any way this can be done in Polars?

```py
    import polars as pl
    data = pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series("col1", [1, 2], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("col2", [3, 4], dtype=pl.Int64)
    ])
    
    namlab = pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series("names", ["col1", "col2"], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("labels", ["This is column 1", "This is column 2"], dtype=pl.Utf8)
    ])
    
    # This is the way I hoped I could assign label attributes
    for nam, lab in namlab.rows():
        data[nam].label = lab
    
    data["col1"].label  # But they are not here: attribute error
    
    # On the other hand I can
    col1 = data["col1"]
    col1.label = "This is column 1"
    col1.label # Retrieve the label: works!
    
    # Perhaps replacing the entire series solves the issue...
    data = data.replace("col1", col1)
    
    data["col1"].label  # Nope: attribute error
```

Comment: In general, I don't think you can add arbitrary attributes to `Series`s and have them stick, as you've discovered.  If your "endgame" is to save those labels as metadata in a parquet file then you can do that with pyarrow, for sure.  However, polars doesn't seem to allow for defined schemas which is where the label would go.

Comment: Agreed with @DeanMacGregor. In danger of sounding like a SO-meme here, but why do you want to do this? That explanation might help us provide an alternative suggestion.

Comment: So I want to create a database API that is equivalent to an R API, see the API tab here: https://africamonitor.ifw-kiel.de/. The data comes in a long table format which has 'Label' as a column, but the default query output should be wide so that each variable is a column, and the description of the variable is somehow attached. The workaround I have for now is to create a data frame with names and labels (equivalent to the one created by collapse::namlab() in my API example), and return this together with the wide data. But this is not ideal of course..

Comment: Relevant issue tracking this feature: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5117